# when i install flutter git is not found from CMD otherwise it works from CMD

Tags: git, flutter, variables, cmd

when i install flutter git is not found from CMD otherwise it works from CMD.
after installing flutter it gives me error that says"where is not recognized as an internal and external command Unable to find git path".

Comment: C:\Users\HP>flutter
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

C:\Users\HP>git version
git version 2.30.0.windows.1

C:\Users\HP>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) The __local__ environment variable `Path` is modified on installation of *Flutter* resulting in neither `git.exe` nor `where.exe` is found anymore. The full qualified file name of `where` is `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe`.

Comment: As Mofi said there might be a problem with Environment variables,you should check the Path.

Answer (score 0):

first u should add a path for flutter from the envirenemnt variable by clicking on Path and 'edit' and 'new' , then past this "C:\srs\flutter\flutter\bin" and save .
then go to CMD and writ 'flutter doctor' to check